# Angular2 Quickstart gulp error

Tags: ubuntu, gulp, angular

I am trying to get angular2 quickstart application up and running but running into errors when I run gulp command.

I have ubuntu 15.04. I installed nodejs v0.10.25 and npm 1.4.21. I also installed gulp v3.9.0. I cloned latest angular2/quickstart using

> git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git hello2ng2

Then I went inside hello2ng2 folder and issued following command

> npm install

And then I issued following command to build the quickstart app

> gulp

I got following errors... not sure how to fix it. Looking for help.

```
[12:38:46] Starting 'default'...
[12:38:46] Starting 'clean'...
[12:38:46] Finished 'clean' after 13 ms
[12:38:46] Starting 'build:ng2'...
npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/angular2/es6/prod/angular2.api.map'
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/rtts_assert/es6/es5build.map'
[12:38:54] 'build:ng2' errored after 7.5 s
[12:38:54] Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'
Message:
    Command failed: npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/angular2/es6/prod/angular2.api.map'
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/rtts_assert/es6/es5build.map'

Details:
    killed: false
    code: 8
    signal: null
    stdout: 
    stderr: npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/angular2/es6/prod/angular2.api.map'
npm WARN package.json rtts_assert@2.0.0-alpha.30 No repository field.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/rtts_assert/es6/es5build.map'

[12:38:54] 'default' errored after 7.52 s
[12:38:54] Error: [object Object]
    at formatError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at finish (/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:53:5)
    at Gulp.onError (/home/usernm/angulartest/helloworld/hello2ng2/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:60:4)
    at Gulp.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

Comment: you can always try the angular2-seed  https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: Try another route: a variety of angular 2 boilerplates sorted by alpha version [here](http://www.tryangular2.com/category/Boilerplate). The repo you've cloned is currently 4 months & 16 versions behind.

Comment: I have the same issue. Take a look at one of the issues [https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/18]. A member of the Angular team mentions: 'We're going to be migrating off of this quickstart soon in lieu of a better solution.'

Comment: Thank you guys, I went to a different example and it worked. Being new to Ubuntu environment, I was initially not sure if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. The tutorial does not (or at least did not when I wrote this) mention the minimum required node version. Install the latest node/npm and give it another go.

Also the latest tutorial is much improved from the time you wrote this, yet it still doesn't indicate the needed node version. After updating node, I highly recommend going through the new [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). I did provide Google some feedback in this item, so hopefully that will be coming soon.